# The largest independent set in a graph and its set of $k$-subsets

Tags: graph-theory

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $G := (V,E)$ be a graph. Consider $G^\prime := (V^\prime,E^\prime)$ with $V^\prime := \{ k \text{-subsets of } V \}$ and $E^\prime := \{(S_1,S_2) \mid S_1 \cup S_2 \text{ is not independent in $G$}\}$.
>
> Show that the largest independent set of $G^\prime$ is the set of all $k$-subsets of a largest independent set of $G$.

Could you please tell me if my proof is correct?

Let $\widetilde{V} \subseteq V^\prime$ the largest independent set of $V^\prime$. Suppose there was an independet set $X \subseteq V(G)$ with $\lvert X \rvert > \lvert \cup_{v^\prime \in \widetilde{V}}v^\prime \rvert$. Then $\widetilde{X}$, the set of $k$-subsets of $X$, would be independent in $G^\prime$ with $\lvert \widetilde{X} \rvert > \lvert \widetilde{V} \rvert$, contradicting the assumption that $\widetilde{V}$ is the largest independent set of $V^\prime$.

Comment: You have not shown that $\widetilde{X}$ is independent in $G'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have everything right, just need to clarify something:

1. If $\tilde{V}\subset V'$ is an independent set of $G'$, then
   then
   $$
   X=\cup_{S\in\tilde{V}}S\qquad\qquad (1)
   $$
   is an independent set of $G$.
   (Let $x,y\in X$ and $xy\in E(G)$. If $x\in S_1$ and $y\in S_2$ for some $S_1,S_2\in\tilde{V}$, then $S_1S_2\in E'$;
   If $x,y\in S$ for some $S$ from $\tilde{V}$, then $SS'\in E'$ for each $S'\in\tilde{V}$.)
2. If $X\subset V$ is an independent set of $G$, then
   $\tilde{X}$, the set of $k$-subsets of $X$, is an independent set of $G'$. This is obvious.

From 1-2 it follows that:

3. If $\tilde{V}\subset V'$ is a maximal independent set of $G'$, then
   the set $X$ given by formula $(1)$ is a maximal independent set of $G$.
4. If $X\subset V$ is a maximal independent set of $G$, then
   $\tilde{X}$ is a maximal independent set of $G'$.

It follows from 1-4, that the largest independent set of $G'$ is the set of all $k$-subsets of a largest independent set of $G$.